# coudn't assign the driver value to an local variable using the constructor, it says illegal invocation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

this is the basetest class am using to invoke the webdriver and driving to another class called landing page. Am trying different classes instead of one, when i debug this code it says illeagal invocation while am sending the driver argument right, at every driver invocation i was able to see the driver instance i have attached the pictures as well, i could use a static keyword and initialize but i want to know why this method is not working.

```
  public class BaseTest {

 WebDriver driver;

public  WebDriver InitDriver() throws IOException {
    
    Properties props = new Properties();
    
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("//filepath");
    props.load(fis);
    
    String browserName = props.getProperty("BROWSER");
    
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    
    
    return driver;
}


public  LandingPage launchApplication() throws IOException {
    driver = InitDriver();
    LandingPage lp = new LandingPage(driver);
    lp.goTo();
    
    return lp;
    
}

 }


 //this is my landing page
  public class LandingPage extends AbstractComponent{


  public String email = "----";
  public String password = "-----";
  WebDriver driver;


 @FindBy(css="#userEmail")
 WebElement UserEmail;


 @FindBy(css="#userPassword")
 WebElement UserPassword;

 @FindBy(id="login")
 WebElement Login;



  public LandingPage(WebDriver driver) {
super(driver);
this.driver = driver;
 }


  public void goTo() {
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/client");
 }


public void loginApplication() {
    
    
    UserEmail.sendKeys(email);
    UserPassword.sendKeys(password);
    Login.click();
    
    
}

   }

  //this is an another class where i have some resuable components
   public class AbstractComponent {
public WebDriver driver;

public AbstractComponent(WebDriver driver) {
```

/* this is where i get illegal invocation error while debugging, code doesn't enter into this constructor */
this.driver = driver;
}

```
// By productsBy = By.cssSelector(".mb-3");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));



public void waitForElementToApper(By findBy) {

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(findBy));

}

public void waitForElementToInvisible(By findBy) {

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(findBy));

}

    }



 Am trying to invoke the inherited class constructor with super keyword in the child class and am     also passing the right arguments. I tried to debug to see if the argument passed is right.
```

[image: driver as an argument for landing page object]

[image: driver in the landing page class super keyword]

[image: driver in the parentclass component]